# Function to plot variable number of subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, graphing

So I have this function,
`func(a,x,y)`
where `x,y` are the graphs coordinates, and `a` some other data (it doesnt really matter what `a` is for this problem)

I want this function to make subplots automatically,
so when the function is called and `n` number of times

```
func(a2,x2,y2)
func(a3,x3,y3)
func(a4,x4,y4)
.
.
func(an,xn,yn)
```

It should show `n` subplots on a graph

*Note it is important that the function works in this way for my usecase, I dont want to be inputting an array of `[a1,a2,...],[x1,x2,...],[y1,y2,...]` and then plotting them all, I want to call each of the graph function seperately*

Comment: what is your subplot definition? (rows? cols?)

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, you can resize the subplots after they are created, and make room for more of them.  It'll be a bit of an accounting chore, but it is possible.  There is no tool to do that with default matplotlib.  Perhaps someone has written a toolbox to do that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you could provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by creating a small sample dataset (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424537/14148248) for example) and providing a plotting function and/or an image, it would help us a lot in answering your question. I think what you are wanting to do is quite feasible but I do not understand what the figure should look like and how exactly `a, x, y` are used to create the subplots.